# Accessing custo attributes inside backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone view, and want to crate custom attributes inside it and access these attributes from other view function.

I have an attribute data:

```
data: {
    response : JSON.parse($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "dashboard/chart/chart-data",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
    }).responseText)

},
```

Inside the initialize function I have access to this.data:

```
initialize: function(ob) {
    var url = ob.route;
    this.render(url);
    console.log(this.data)
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'callback':this.drawChart, 'packages':['corechart']});
},
```

Which logs Object {response: Object}

But in another function, drawChart,

console.log(this.data) gives me undefined

and console.log(this) gives me:

```
Window {top: Window, location: Location, document: document, window: Window, external: Object…}
```

How can I change the scope inside drawChart, so that this references the backbone view object, and not the window element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `drawChart` to the view instance. Pass `this.drawChart.bind(this)` as the callback in the `google.load` options.

Comment: No problem. When you pass a function as an argument or property to another API like this it is your responsibility to ensure it will be called with the correct context. `Function.prototype.bind` is a convenient native function for doing this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind